# were supposed to have come [or] had been supposed to come

Tags: grammar

Just wondering which one is correct. The book is written in past tense, and this refers to events in the story's past, in the previous book:

1. **The pair were supposed to have come with them**, but they'd gotten trapped inside the dome.
2. **The pair had been supposed to come with them,** but they'd gotten trapped inside the dome.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why do you think one of them is correct? Why do you think one of them is incorrect?

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure if the first one works in past perfect

Comment: The pair were (was) supposed to have come with them, but they got trapped inside the dome.